# Parsing of DateTime with timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

Here is my code:

```
DateTime dateTime;
string str = "2016-02-11 23:02:30 -0500";
if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateTime))
{

}
```

I am receiving `{2/12/2016 7:02:30 AM}` as dateTime result. But I want to get `2/11/2016`, is it possible?

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: You want to change the way DateTime look in your IDE? Or you want to change how it is displayed to user? For first one: It comes from system; You can change from datetime setting of your system. For second one, try formatting datetime to desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `TimeZoneInfo`:

```
DateTime dateTime;
string str = "2016-02-11 23:02:30 -0500";
if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateTime))
{
    // error
}

dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

var serverTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local; // Server time zone
var allTimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(); // Time zone list

var clientTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Hawaiian Standard Time");

// DateTime in server time zone
var dateTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTime, clientTimeZone.Id, serverTimeZone.Id);
```

Take a look at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Apx51v

**Note:**

And remember, `DateTime` doesn't contains time-zone information.

> "A developer is responsible for keeping track of time-zone information associated with a DateTime value via some external mechanism"
>   [DateTime in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to  use DateTimeOffset.Parse() to parse string into DateTimeOffset object with represented offset and than format it to string without it("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in example)

Answer (score 0):

Since your string has [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset) instead of `DateTime`.

```
DateTimeOffset dto;
string str = "2016-02-11 23:02:30 -0500";
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{
   //Success
}
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{11.02.2016 23:02:30 -05:00}` and you can use it's [`.DateTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime) which returns `11.02.2016 23:02:30`.

[image]